# Not getting files in folder directory even after getting permission and files in the folder in android

Tags: java, android, android-file

I am not getting file directory even after getting permission in android.I put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in Manifest file. and I added

`Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`.

The permission window popup, and in allowing the permission in app. still I getting **dir as exist but number of files are zero **.

Here my full code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    ArrayList<Object> filesList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final int GALLERY_PERMISSION_CODE = 1002;
    private File[] files;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("Omm","GalleryPermission before");
        GalleryPermission();
        Log.i("Omm","GalleryPermission after");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        sb.append(File.separator);
        sb.append("ABC/Media/.abc");
        Log.i("Omm"," STATUS_DIR before");

        File STATUS_DIR = new File(sb.toString());
        Log.i("Omm"," STATUS_DIR after "+ sb.toString() );
        Log.i("Omm", "dir exists = "+STATUS_DIR.exists());
        
        /****CALLING FUNCTION************/
        getData();
        /****CALLING FUNCTION************/

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void GalleryPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
                    && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                String[] galleryPermissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                requestPermissions(galleryPermissions, GALLERY_PERMISSION_CODE);
            } else {
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
    
    private ArrayList<Object> getData() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        sb.append(File.separator);
        sb.append("Abc/Media/efg");//Consider this folder exits and 
                                           //contains data.
        Log.i("Omm", "ArrayList inovked");
        StoryModel f;



        String targetPath = sb.toString();
        File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
        files = targetDirector.listFiles();

        /**************I AM GETTING FILESLENGTH AS ZERO*****BUT I HAVE FILE IN THAT DIRECTORY**************/
        Log.i("Omm", "Files = "+files.length);
        /**************I AM GETTING FILESLENGTH AS ZERO*****BUT I HAVE FILE IN THAT DIRECTORY**************/
        if (files == null) {
            Log.i("Omm", "Null");
        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                File file = files[i];
                f = new StoryModel();
                f.setName("NBM Story Saver: " + (i + 1));
                f.setUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
                f.setPath(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                f.setFilename(file.getName());
                filesList.add(f);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /**************I AM GETTING FILESLIST AS ZERO*****BUT I HAVE FILE IN THAT DIRECTORY**************/
        Log.i("Omm", "dir exists = "+filesList.size());
        /**************I AM GETTING FILESLIST AS ZERO*****BUT I HAVE FILE IN THAT DIRECTORY**************/
        return filesList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Underneath `File STATUS_DIR = new File(sb.toString());` call - `Log.i("Omm", "dir exists = "+STATUS_DIR.exist());`

Comment: It returns true, how to get values from those files?

Comment: what "values" do you want to get?

Comment: You are on Android Q?

Comment: `CheckDirExist(files);` That is the wrong aproach. Change to `CheckDirExist(STATUS_DIR);` and implement your function differently. Or yet better use STATUS_DIR.exists() to check if a directory exists. Your function name does not cover the code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply  @HB.  Yes, I am using Android Q and using androidX directory files. I can able to find whether the folder exists or not. But I am not able to get a list of the files, it always returns zero. (i.e) if a folder as whatup->image folder, the image folder contains some files like 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg... I can able to find the folder exists or not, but I am not able to get 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg files list(which is list of files).it always returns zero.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @blackapps Yes, I am using Android Q and using androidX directory files. I can able to find whether the folder exists or not. But I am not able to get a list of the files, it always returns zero. (i.e) if a folder as whatup->image folder, the image folder contains some files like 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg... I can able to find the folder exists or not, but I am not able to get 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg files list(which is list of files).it always returns zero

Comment: What you ate saying is that .listFiles() returns null for an getExternalStorageDirectory() path. Yes that is normal under Android Q. You can read that here every day. For the last six months this has been reported here twice aday.

Comment: Further you threat sb.append("WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/1.jpg") as a directory. But it is a file path. Below Q you cannot list files for a file too.

Comment: There is a statement you can add to your manifest file and then you can do the listing.

Comment: Yes, @blackapps, actually I am getting the folder, but unfortunately, while putting here I mistakenly added that file... is any way to get the files in a folder under android Q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added  `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` inside AndroidMainfest.xml at `<application>` tag.

It's working fine.